# Where are the Grey Havens?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, middle-earth, map

I was looking at a map of Middle-Earth earlier, when I stumbled across a location labeled 'Grey Havens'. However, as I understand it, the Grey Havens are supposed to be quite far away, on a separate continent.

So is there a reason why such a place would be labeled as such on this map? The only thing I can think of is that this is the place the ships to the Grey Havens sail from, but I still have a hard time believing that.

[image]

Comment: Just past Upminster on the District line.

Comment: @Valorum Hey, that's where I live...never seen the Elves though!

Comment: You may have seen the Grey Havens referred to throughout Tolkien’s works as _Mithlond_; that’s their Sindarin name. Also, I’m a bit surprised that such a reasonably detailed map wouldn’t include Michel Delving (or Great Smials) at all.

Comment: The common name for Emyn Uial seems to be an error as well. Hills of Evendi**u**m.

Comment: Please don't forget to tag your Middle-Earth related question with the tag "Tolkien".

Comment: @hobbs _Evendium_ being, of course, a metallic element that always retains the exact same level of dimness, regardless of external light sources.

Comment: @Maksim , the "Tolkien" tag is used specifically for questions about the author, just like the "George R. R. Martin" tag as well as the "JKRowling" tag, among other authors of large universes who generate a large amount of questions. ["Let's figure out our Tolkien tags"](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10161/68872) may help solve any queries.

Comment: @Edlothiad, to the contrary, any legendarium-related question can (and should) be tagged "Tolkien". It's much more convenient when you search for such questions than when they only get tagged by the book title. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien

Comment: then 80% of posts are missing that tag. Author tags should be consistent. Tolkien tags should be kept to questions related to the author, bring it up on meta if you disagree, that is how questions are being tagged...

Comment: The obligatory +1 to you for a hand-drawn circle :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### No, this is correct

The Grey Havens are where Círdan maintains the Elven ships that travel over the Sea. This is also mentioned a few times in the text; for example (emphasis mine):

> 'And I've heard tell that Elves are moving west. They do say they are going to the harbours, out away beyond the White Towers.' Sam waved his arm vaguely: neither he nor any of them knew how far it was to the Sea, past the old towers beyond the western borders of the Shire. But it was an old tradition that away over there stood **the Grey Havens, from which at times elven-ships set sail, never to return**.
>
> <sup>*Fellowship of the Ring* Book I Chapter 2: "The Shadow of the Past"</sup>

It's possible that you're confusing the Grey Havens with Alqualondë, the haven of the Teleri on the shores of Aman:

> [M]any pearls they won for themselves from the sea, and their halls were of pearl, and of pearl were the mansions of Olwë at Alqualondë, the Haven of the Swans, lit with many lamps. For that was their city, and the haven of their ships; and those were made in the likeness of swans, with beaks of gold and eyes of gold and jet.
>
> <sup>*The Silmarillion* III *Quenta Silmarillion* Chapter 5: "Of Eldamar and the Princes of the Eldalië"</sup>

Alqualondë is indeed on a separate continent from Middle-earth, though this is only true until the fall of Númenor in the middle of the Second Age; after that Aman is removed from the world, and is more akin to a separate planet rather than a separate continent. But these two havens are not the same place.

You may also be getting confused by Falas, Círdan's base of operations in the First Age, which is also described as "Havens":

> [T]here came also great numbers of the Grey-elves, wanderers of the woods of Beleriand and folk of the Havens, with Círdan their lord.
>
> <sup>*The Silmarillion* III *Quenta Silmarillion* Chapter 13: "Of the Return of the Noldor"</sup>

The Havens of Falas were in Beleriand, which was a region in the west of Middle-earth; while not a continent, it was indeed rather far from the Shire, but Beleriand (and therefore Falas) were destroyed at the end of the First Age, and sank into the sea.